# How do you make a make a page's worth of empty space (with only a title) followed by a div in CSS?

Tags: html, css, positioning, fullscreen

I have a webpage I have been working on and I want to have a static background. The idea is to have the page initially only show a title and the background and have you scroll down for content (a div that fills up the entire width of the browser and has a filled background). The page has a navbar at the top that already spans the entire width of the screen. My question is, how to you make this possible? Here is the code I tried, which didn't quite do the trick. I have nothing for the CSS in main.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>


        <div class="topspace">
            <h1 class="mainTitle">Title</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="main">
            Bottom content<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.navbar {
    background-color: #708090;
    margin: 0 0 auto;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.navbar ul {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.navbar ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.navbar ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #DDD;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border: 0;
}

.navbar ul li a:hover {
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #222;
}

.topspace {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

.mainTitle {

    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-top: 40%;
    color: #B22222;
}

.wrapper {
    border:0;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    background: rgba(0, 100, 100, 0.6);
}
```

Here is a JSFiddle for this code, though it is not displayed quite as it looks on my browser http://jsfiddle.net/xpkayL9t/

Comment: You seems to be a regular visitor of stackoverflow , you may be aware of creating fiddle of the code kinldy do it if possible ! rickyman20

Comment: Oh! Yes... Though fiddle doesn't display it as it does on my browser. Here it is. I'll put it on the actual question http://jsfiddle.net/xpkayL9t/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the background cover

just look at this

http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: I have the background set up, the problem is actually creating a div that not only covers an entire "page space" but also allows for content bellow it, so you scroll down and you can see more content

Comment: well the background should be for your first div containing the content then

Comment: I think I'm bad at explaining my thoughts. I was thinking about a div that covers the entire height and width of the screen with an h1 centered, followed by a div with content, except with a color as a background, so that when you scroll, the bottom one moves up. I only seem to have a problem is making the top div be the size of the screen

Comment: oh well you will need to use jquery or javascript to set it to the height of the window

Comment: Oh, I thought about using javascript but I thought CSS ought to have a way of doing it by itself. I'll look into that